# How to remove pointer-events from all children of the element with a dragover event?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I created a global `dragover` event listener so that when something it dragged over the page it would show a dragover area on the page and hide it when you move the cursor off the page:

```
 document.addEventListener('dragover', event => { 
   event.preventDefault()
   this.dragOverArea = true
   // ...
 })

 document.addEventListener('dragleave', event => { 
   event.preventDefault()
   this.dragOverArea = false
   // ...
 })
```

### Problem

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ct3haqf0

Try dragging any file over the elements on the page (from the top left) you will see the `dragover` event switching to `dragleave` rapidly back and forth which makes the drop area appear/disappear while you dragging it through the elements.

In my project it creates a noticeable lag. The problem is, `dragover` event conflicts with all the element's children (and hence activates `dragleave`), so it constantly shows/hides the drop area while you're dragging something over the page full of elements

### Question

I found that you're supposed to set: `pointer-events: none` to all the children of the element with `dragover` listener, so I have to set this rule to `body * { }`

So how do I set this rule to all children of the `body` with JS inside `addEventListener('dragover')` ?

Comment: `so that when something it dragged over the page` what is `something`? This question is very unclear to me

Comment: @DarrenSweeney it doesn't matter really, any page element that has `draggable` or any external element like file

Answer (score 3):

What about adding an class to the body, which can be styled with CSS?

adding classes:

```
function addClassToBody( newClass )
{
    document.body.className += " "+newClass+" ";
}

function removeClassFromBody( oldClass )
{
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(" "+oldClass+" "," ");
}
```

CSS:

```
body.drag * {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

I tested it in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timlg07/4fdj0hvc/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure why it's still not working me. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ct3haqf0/  try dragging any file over the `grey` area (body) you will see the drop area appear, but if you drag it through other elements on the page (from the top left) then `dragover` event keeps switching to `dragleave` and the drop area constantly appears/disappears very rapidly

Comment: You have to make the body and html size to 100%. It called the dragleave every time when you entered the body (whose size was only 100*20px)

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out.

### Here's an example

I'm using Vue.js so `dragging` and `showDropZone` are just variables in `data()`.

**html**

```
  <div 
      v-show="showDropZone === true"
      id="drop-zone"
      class="drop-zone"
   >
      Drop zone text
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
  // In the component with the drop zone div:
  document.getElementById('drop-zone').addEventListener('drop', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.showDropZone = false
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files
  })


  // In the entry component:
  window.addEventListener('dragenter', event => { 
      this.dragging++;
      this.showDropZone = true

      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
  });


  window.addEventListener('dragover', event => { 
      this.showDropZone = true

      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
  });


  window.addEventListener('dragleave', event => { 
      this.dragging--;
      if (this.dragging === 0) {
          this.showDropZone = false
      }

      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
  });
```